mathematica nested integrals break in parallel computing environment
I am doing a quadruple nested integral and noticed that it produces inconsistent results when in a parallel computing environment.
$Assumptions = Element[{j, k}, Integers];
foo = ParallelTable[
    Integrate[
     Integrate[
      Integrate[
       Integrate[
        E^(-I j t1 \[Delta] + I j t2 \[Delta] - I k t3 \[Delta] + 
          I j t4 \[Delta]) h^3 , {t4, 0, t3}], {t3, 0, t2}], {t2, 0, 
       t1}], {t1, 0, 2 \[Pi]/\[Delta]}], {i, 1}] // Simplify;
bar = Integrate[
    Integrate[
     Integrate[
      Integrate[ 
       E^(-I j t1 \[Delta] + I j t2 \[Delta] - I k t3 \[Delta] + 
         I j t4 \[Delta]) h^3, {t4, 0, t3}], {t3, 0, t2}], {t2, 0, 
      t1}], {t1, 0, 2 \[Pi]/\[Delta]}] // Simplify;

bar // Simplify

for me this produces
-((2 I h^3 \[Pi])/(j (j - k) (-2 j + k) \[Delta]^4))
-((2 I h^3 \[Pi])/(j (j - k) k \[Delta]^4))
I should get the exact same answer but I do not. Can anyone reproduce this?
Also the same integral can be written as Integrate[f, range1, range2, ...] and this does produce the same result. But in the parallel environment again this is inconsistent with the expression Integrate[Integrate[f, ... This only happens when I include some extra terms...
foo = ParallelTable[
    Integrate[
     Integrate[
      Integrate[
       Integrate[
        Sy^4 \[CapitalOmega]^4 8 I a h^3 E^(-I j t1 \[Delta] + 
          I j t2 \[Delta] - I k t3 \[Delta] + 
          I j t4 \[Delta])   , {t4, 0, t3}], {t3, 0, t2}], {t2, 0, 
       t1}], {t1, 0, 2 \[Pi]/\[Delta]}], {i, 1}] // Simplify;
bar = ParallelTable[
    Integrate[
     Sy^4 \[CapitalOmega]^4 h^3 8 I a h^3 E^(-I j t1 \[Delta] + 
       I j t2 \[Delta] - I k t3 \[Delta] + I j t4 \[Delta])  , {t1, 0,
       2 \[Pi]/\[Delta]}, {t2, 0, t1}, {t3, 0, t2}, {t4, 0, t3}], {i, 
     1}] // Simplify;

foo // Simplify
bar // Simplify

Produces different answers. But if you remove the parallelTable command, it is easy to check that these two integrals are identical.
